# Hardware Configuration Check on a New Laptop

Tags: windows-7, thinkpad

First of all I must say I am quite lame in computer hardware.

I just got my Lenovo Laptop T400 today. It is preinstalled with Windows 7. 
I would like to see if the configurations of the laptop are actually the same as what is in my order, so I look up the configurations of the laptop in device manager of Windows 7 and do the comparison.
CPU and Wireless card are the same, but for other parts I am not quite sure:

```
                my order                              ->   Win-7 device manager
                =========                                  ====================
Monitors:       14.1 WXGA+ TFT, w/ LED Backlight      ->   ThinkPad Display 1440x900  
Graphics card:  ATI Mobility Radeon 3470 with 256MB   ->   ATI Mobility Radeon HD 3400 Series  
Battery:        6 cell Li-Ion Battery                 ->   "Microsoft ACPI-Compliant Control Method Battery"
                                                      ->   and "Microsoft Composite Battery"  
expansion:      ExpressCard Slot & PC Card Slot       ->   ?? (don't know where to look up the info)  
Memory:         2GB PC3-8500 DDR3 (1 DIMM)            ->   ?? (don't know where to look up the info)  
Hard drive:     250 GB Hard Disk Drive, 5400rpm       ->   WDC WD2500BEVS-08VAT2 
DVD/CD drive:   DVD-RW 8x Dual Layer, SATA/Ultrabay   ->   HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GSA-U20N
```

In particular,

- For the monitor, I wonder how to verify "WXGA+", "TFT" and "LED"?
- For the Graphics card, are "3470" and "HD 3400 Series" different?
- For memory and System expansion slots, I wonder where to look up the info under Windows 7.
- For DVD/CD_ROM drive, are they the same?
- For battery, how to verify there are "6" cells? On the battery bar, I saw a "5" in a circle formed by two arrows end in head. Does it mean only 5 cells?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think Lenovo didn't ship you what you paid for?

Comment: I have friends telling me Lenovo messed up with their ordered parts. Since I am not familiar with hardware, I think I had better to be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, let me introduce you to some useful Lenovo-specific diagnostic tools:**

- Lenovo System Toolbox

  - Large set of detailed diagnostics and repair tools. For example, this tool looks up your system's serial number and checks how many days are left in the warranty.
  - More info at this [blog post](http://lenovoblogs.com/insidethebox/?p=168).
  - May not be installed by default; [download here](http://www-307.ibm.com/pc/support/site.wss/document.do?sitestyle=lenovo&lndocid=MIGR-67520).
- Thinkvantage Power Manager

  - Battery and power management tailored for your Lenovo hardare and OS combination.
  - Should be installed by default; try right-clicking the battery icon in the system tray.

**Now, to address your specific hardware questions:**

Windows cannot always specifically identify each piece of hardware. This is because the operating system abstracts the hardware interface via drivers so it can interoperate with many kinds of hardware. Often one generic driver will work with many types of devices of the same class, even from different manufacturers.

Having said that, I will try to assist you in comfirming you have the right hardware. (I don't think you should be too worried about this, though.) Overall, I think all the hardware matches your order.

One quick tip: Google is your friend. Try searching for unique-looking model numbers and acronyms like "WXGA+" and "WDC WD2500BEVS-08VAT2." Let's look at each piece:

> For the monitor, I wonder how to
>   verify "WXGA+", "TFT" and "LED"?

**Looks OK:** WXGA+ refers to the screen's native resolution. WXGA+ means 1440X900 pixels.
TFT refers to the LCD technology.
And LED refers to the type of light that is used to illuminate the screen from the back.

> For the Graphics card, are "3470" and
>   "HD 3400 Series" different?

**Looks OK:** As I explained above, Windows often does not need to/is unable to identify a specific piece of hardware due to driver abstraction. "3400 Series" indicates this driver works for a family of video cards including your "3470."

> For memory and System expansion slots,
>   I wonder where to look up the info
>   under Windows 7.

Try running "msinfo32.exe." Should work on any version of Windows.

OR for much more detailed information:

1. Start the Lenovo System Toolbox mentioned above.
2. Click "Diagnostics and Tools."
3. (Dismiss the message about not being able to find something by clicking "OK.")
4. Click "system information"
5. Optional: Click "Advanced View" for even more information.

> For DVD/CD_ROM drive, are they the
>   same?

Both msinfo32.exe and the Lenovo System Toolbox will provide more detailed info. Or Google the part number you found.

> For battery, how to verify there are
>   "6" cells? On the battery bar, I saw a
>   "5" in a circle formed by two arrows
>   end in head. Does it mean only 5
>   cells?

Find the part number for the battery in Thinkvantage Power manager and google it. The part number for my X301 6-cell is: 42T4643

Comment: Thanks! For battery, mine part number is 43T4653. Googled it but found nothing.

Answer (score 2):

**For the monitor, I wonder how to verify "WXGA+", "TFT" and "LED"?**

The t400 comes with a backlit TFT. Do you see backlighting when it's on? You should be good. WXGA+ just refers to the 1440x900 resolution.

**For the Graphics card, are "3470" and "HD 3400 Series" different?**

No, 3470 is part of the 3400 series.

**For memory and System expansion slots, I wonder where to look up the info under Windows 7.**

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php) will tell you available slots and which ones currently contain what.

**For DVD/CD_ROM drive, are they the same?**

Most DVD drives these days work fine with CDs as well. Your specific model does.

**For battery, how to verify there are "6" cells? On the battery bar, I saw a "5" in a circle formed by two arrows end in head. Does it mean only 5 cells?**

Check the voltage and mAh (milliampere-hour) ratings on it to get a better idea. One cell is typically 3.6 - 3.7V and 2400mAh.

Comment: Thanks! For battery, its voltoage is 12.5V and no current because my laptop is on AC. if a cell is indeed 3.6V, then there is 3 or 4 cells?

Comment: Sounds like 3 cells in series with 4800mAh (3 in series - 2x3 = 6) so it's 56Wh 6-cell. You could also check by weight, the 6-cell with the laptop will weigh 5lbs 4.8oz and 5lbs 10.8oz with 9-cell.

Comment: Thanks John T! Yes it's design capacity is 56.16Wh. (1) do you mean 3 cells in series and another 3 cells in series and then the two groups parallel? (2) how do you calculate 56Wh from 4800mAh and 12.5V? (3) the current remaning capacity is 58.73Wh, does this mean my battery is overchanged?

Comment: 12.5V is probably the input for the charger. I think the battery is 10.8V. You need a bit of an electrical engineering background to understand things easier, a bit of math helps too! :) check out the wiki page for Lithium Ion batteries if you're interested: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery